# How can I construct a grammar that generates this language? grammar context-free-grammar

Tags: automation, grammar, context-free-grammar

I'm studying for a finite automata & grammars test and I'm stuck with this question:

Construct a grammar that generates L:
L = {a^n b^m c^2n | n>=0, m>=0}

How can I construct a grammar that generates this language?
grammar context-free-grammar automata

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick. I verified this on http://mdaines.github.io/grammophone/ .

S -> a B c c 
    | a S c c
    | .

B -> b B 
    | .

Comment: Please [do not post an answer that consists essentially of a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include the important points in your answer; leave the link for extra information or as a reference.

Comment: Careful around your edge cases. This cannot generate strings of only b's, for instance. The answer would also benefit from some discussion of how you arrived here.

Comment: I'm also a beginner in this subject and also to stack overflow. Thank you for correcting me. Should I edit my answer or explain why my solution is wrong?

Comment: @NihalNayak If you know how to correct your solution, then definitely correct it! Also explain how you came up with that as it will be more helpful to others when they need to make a CFG for other languages. My answer shows some of my thought process but your way of thinking about the problem is probably different. By providing different ways of thinking about and solving a problem we give more users a better understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I find it always helps with these kinds of questions to come up with some rules for how to build big strings out of little strings. First, identify the littlest strings in your language. In our case, we can start with the observation that if n = 0, b^m is in our language; that is, w in b* is in our language. We then note that if x is a string in our language we get another string by adding one a on the left and two cs on the right; that is, axcc is a string in our language also. So our rules are:

1. b* in L
2. if x in L then axcc in L

Writing this in terms of a CFG is now straightforward:

```
S -> B
S -> aScc
```

Here, S generates our language L and B generates the language b*. We complete the grammar by providing a grammar for b* with start symbol B:

```
(1) S -> B
(2) S -> aScc
(3) B -> e
(4) B -> B
```

Any string a^n b^m c^2n can be generated using n applications of rule 2, 1 application of rule 1, m applications of rule 4 and 1 application of rule 3. That this grammar generates no strings not in the language is left as an exercise.